# convert column to date time in pandas(Data Cleaning)

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

i have a column which is of format h:m:s:ms dd/mm/yy(but not consistent) [image: col3 date field]
Unique values of the column are [image: unique values of date field] as you can see the format is not consistent some have a year as 04 and some as 2004. some have tab spaces. so I want to clean and convert it into a DateTime data type currently it is object  [image: object data type]. I am directly using this code [image: code I used] and it  doesn't work how to overcome this problem

Comment: Is possible post `df.col3.unique()` like text?

Comment: hi jezrael, you can access here:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprabhala-cpu/Machine-Learning/main/datetime.txt

Comment: @jezrael i have another problem relating to dates if you can solve that would be helpful you can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302133/merging-on-date-column-df1-date-is-datetime64ns-utc-and-df2-date-is-datetime6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First is necessary remove trailing spaces with `\t` values, replace possible `\t` to spaces and split with join formats in swapped ordering.

```
#https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sprabhala-cpu/Machine-Learning/main/datetime.txt
df = pd.DataFrame({'col3':a})

s = df['col3'].str.strip(' \t').str.replace('\t',' ').str.split()
dates_str = s.str[1] + ' ' + s.str[0]
```

Then is defined formats in list and in function is generated only matched datetimes and combined by [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) to final datetimes.

*Important notice - order of format in list is important, because some months with days should be interpret 2 ways.

It means e.g. `23:59:00.00  08.07.2004` - it is August or July? In formats is first specified `%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f` and then `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f` - so here is parsed like first is month - August. If need `July` is necessary first defined `%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f` and then `%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f`.

```
from functools import reduce 

def convert_formats_to_datetimes(s1, formats):
    out = [pd.to_datetime(s1, format=x, errors='coerce') for x in formats]
    return reduce(lambda l,r: pd.Series.combine_first(l,r), out)

formats = ['%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S.%f', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
           '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f','%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
           '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f',
           '%m/%d/%y %M:%S.%f', '%d/%m/%y %M:%S.%f',
           '%m/%d/%Y %M:%S.%f', '%m.%d.%Y %M:%S.%f',
           ]

df['date_time'] = convert_formats_to_datetimes(dates_str, formats)
```

---

```
print (df)
                        col3           date_time
0      23:59:00.00  31/07/04 2004-07-31 23:59:00
1         59:00.0\t4/11/1930 1930-04-11 00:59:00
2        23:59:00.00  2/4/14 2014-04-02 23:59:00
3      23:59:00.00  30/06/04 2004-06-30 23:59:00
4      23:59:00.00  31/05/04 2004-05-31 23:59:00
..                       ...                 ...
315    23:59:00.00\t12/30/04 2004-12-30 23:59:00
316    23:59:00.00  30/05/04 2004-05-30 23:59:00
317   23:59:00.00\t4/10/1930 1930-10-04 23:59:00
318     23:59:00.00 30/07/04 2004-07-30 23:59:00
319     23:59:00.00  3/30/04 2004-03-30 23:59:00

[320 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation , really helpful